# Vue Cli unit test with jest how to run single test

Tags: vuejs2, jestjs, vue-cli-3

I have vue application using the vue cli 3.
During the setup process i chose jest as the testing framework.
To run my unit tests i have a script in the package.json:

```
test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit",
```

and to run this i write in the vs code terminal:

```
npm run test:unit
```

This runs all my tests that meet the specifications set up in the jest config section of the package.json file.

My question is how to run just a single test. Is there a specific command i need to run? or is there an vscode extension that will work with this setup.

Comment: i have tried to install jest-runner extension for vscode but when i try to run a test it always says "test suite failed to run"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I run a single test using Jest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42827054/how-do-i-run-a-single-test-using-jest)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If you want to execute only single file then simply do:

```
npm run test:unit -t counter
OR
npm run test:unit counter
```

Whereas counter.spec.js is the my test file.

Comment: This does not work for me. It simply says `0 passing` and runs no tests.

Comment: I had to do `npm run test:unit -t tests/unit/Foo.spec.ts`.

Answer (score 7):

The Vue CLI service respects Jest's CLI options, so you can append them to commands in `package.json`, e.g

```js
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit",
    "test:only": "vue-cli-service test:unit --testPathPattern=user.store",
  },
  "dependencies": {
```

`testPathPattern` takes a regex which applies to the spec file names, so in my tests if I specify the pattern

```
--testPathPattern=user.store
```

I run a single spec file, but if I specify

```
--testPathPattern=store
```

I run multiple matching spec files with `store` in the name.

Here is the [Jest docs ref](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/cli#testpathpattern-regex)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. This runs all the tests within that specific spec file, and not "a single test"

Comment: @coler-j, you could try `it.only(...)` alongside with the `testPathPattern` option.

Answer (score 3):

For that you can use the `only` method. It can be chained on to the `test` method directly.

*myunittests.spec.js*

```
describe('My Unit Tests', () => {
    test('My excluded test', () => {
        ...
    })

    test.only('my single test', () => {
        ...
    })
})
```

After that you can run the tests by running `npm run test:unit -t myunittests`.

There is also a `skip` method that can be chained.

*myunittests.spec.js*

```
describe('My Unit Tests', () => {
    test('My excluded test', () => {
        ...
    })

    test.skip('my single test', () => {
        ...
    })
})
```

By running `npm run test:unit -t myunittests` again you will see all 'other' tests are running.