# Trying to use -t or --testNamePattern in Jest runs all tests

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, testing, jestjs, ts-jest

I'm using `jest` and `ts-jest` configured in the way `ts-jest` describes in their docs.

If I run `yarn test --listTests` I can see the test file I want to run: `processNewUser.ts` included in the output in a `__test__` folder in my project.

I can run that test only with `yarn test --testPathPattern='processNewUser'`

But If I try use `yarn test --testNamePattern='Processes new user. Auth'` which is the name of the test, then every test runs, including all with no name string like what is specified.

Same with:
`yarn test -t="Auth"`
`yarn test -t Auth`
`yarn test --testNamePattern "Auth"`
`jest Auth`
`jest -t="Processes"`
etc etc.
and every combo of syntax really. Also tried this with naming a `describe` function wrapper instead of a test. No luck.

My `tsconfig.json` is:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "lib": [
      "ES2020.Promise",
      "ES2015.Iterable",
      "ES2015.Symbol.WellKnown"
    ],
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
}
```

My `jest.config.ts` is:

```
import type {Config} from '@jest/types';
const config: Config.InitialOptions = {
  clearMocks: true,
  coverageDirectory: 'coverage',
  coverageProvider: 'v8',
  moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'json', 'jsx', 'ts', 'tsx', 'node'],
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  setupFiles: ['dotenv/config'],
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['./jest.setup.js'],
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.tsx?$': 'ts-jest',
    '^.+\\.ts?$': 'ts-jest',
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/', '\\.pnp\\.[^\\/]+$'],
  
}

export default config;
```

Yarn script is just: `"test": "jest",`

I want this to be able to tag a test with `auth` for example to have all auth tests run.

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same error, but I found that in reality the error was because I was concatenating the rest of the code with npm, which for some reason doesn't add these extra commands along with the script in the package.json

using yarn to run

[exemple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KcQRY.png)

Comment: I ended up discovering that to run with npm we have to add the `--` symbols after the script name

`npm t --watch // ❌ dont work`

`npm t -- --watch // ✅ work`

Answer (score 0):

The predicate for filtering out tests by name is defined [here](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/0a902e1/packages/jest-jasmine2/src/index.ts#L162-L165):

```js
  if (globalConfig.testNamePattern) {
    const testNameRegex = new RegExp(globalConfig.testNamePattern, 'i');
    env.specFilter = (spec: Spec) => testNameRegex.test(spec.getFullName());
  }
```

Notice that it checks created regexp against **full name** of each spec. I.e. the name of the test suite itself plus names of **all surrounding describe blocks**.

Comment: thats just a definition, but no explanation for "why does jest run all tests, when i filter tests by a pattern?" as i understand, filters can only filter by spec-name (`describe('spec-name')`), and fine-grained control is possible with [test.only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42827054/how-do-i-run-a-single-test-using-jest)