# How keep tests shortcuts/icons once `auto-run` is switched off from the extension sidebar?

Tags: jestjs, vscode-extensions, vscode-jest

Currently Jest in my VSCode uses the `--watch` parameter (I use the `Orta.vscode-jest` extension), which mean when I save a file, it will run all tests in uncommitted files.

It's a good default behavior but sometimes my upcoming commit may imply multiple files and I don't want to waste 75% of my time and resources on tests I don't to focus on.

After reading documentation, I found I can turn off the `auto-run` (see arrow below), so now when saving nothing happens, and I was expecting a way to trigger manually the test I want.

[image]

Unfortunately once done it's like if the extension was totally shut down. See below, I have no longer the ability to run tests through the extension.

[image]

Do you know a way to solve this? Keeping icon buttons to trigger manually specific tests?

I saw some homemade solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/55279902/3608410 (see `Running a selected Jest test in Visual Studio Code`) but I feel it's weird since we have a powerful extension already installed.

(maybe I missed something...)

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Didn't see that before but if doing a right click in the test file where needed, in the menu I'm able to run a specific test, handy!

[image]