# react native jest is calling many more tests when I just call just 1 test suite

Tags: react-native, jestjs

I just called `jest src/containers/components/VerificationView.test.js --runTestsByPath --verbose` and it just has 1 simple test:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, act, fireEvent, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react-native';
import VerificationView from './VerificationView';

describe('Verification Screen', () => {

    beforeEach(() => {
        jest.useFakeTimers();
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        jest.runAllTimers();
    })

    it('should render without errors', async () => {

        const verificationRes = {VerificationR: {status:1}};
        const login = jest.fn();
        const authContextValue = { login }; // Mock the context value
        var wrapper = render(
            <VerificationView  />
        );

        await wrapper.update();
        expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
    });
});
```

but the test run calls many other files:

```
 PASS  src/containers/components/VerificationView.test.js
  RenderLang component
    ✓ should render without errors (24 ms)
    ✓ should call handler onPress (7 ms)
    ✓ render while activeLang is selected (3 ms)
    ✓ render while activeLang is not selected (2 ms)
  Signup component
    ✓ Signup component renders correctly (55 ms)
    ✓ Signup login button press (24 ms)
    ✓ Signup back button press (17 ms)
    ✓ Signup btnTNC button press (20 ms)
    ✓ Signup btnSignup button press (17 ms)
    ✓ Signup setPassword change text (18 ms)
    ✓ Signup setPassword change text (18 ms)
    ✓ Signup setPhone change text (16 ms)
    ✓ Signup setPhone change text empty (29 ms)
    ✓ Signup setEmail change text (18 ms)
    ✓ Signup setLName change text (16 ms)
    ✓ Signup setFName change text (18 ms)
  Verification Screen
    ✓ should render without errors (31 ms)
```

And a snip from my jest.config.js

```
testMatch: [
        "<rootDir>/src/**/*.test.js"
    ],
    testPathIgnorePatterns: ["/node_modules/", "e2e/", "__mocks__/"],
    testEnvironmentOptions: { url: 'http://localhost/' },
    //transform: {
    //    //"^.+\\.(js|jsx)$": "<rootDir>/jest.preprocessor.js"
    //},
    transform: {
        //"^.+\\.(js|jsx)$": "<rootDir>/jest.preprocessor.js",
        "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest"
    },
    //transform: {
    //    '^.+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$': [
    //        'babel-jest',
    //        { configFile: './babel.config.js' }, // <- cannot use rootDir here
    //    ],
    //},
    transformIgnorePatterns: [
        //"/node_modules/(?!(jest-)?@codler)",
        //"node_modules/.*/react-native-vector-icons.*",
        //"node_modules/(?!(@react-native|react-native|native-base.*|react-native-easy-grid|react-native-drawer|@react-native-community|react-native-vector-icons)/)",
        "node_modules\/(?!(@react-native|react-native|native-base.*|react-native-element-dropdown|react-native-image-crop-picker|react-native-easy-grid|react-native-drawer|@react-native-community|@react-native-firebase|react-native-vector-icons|@codler|@twotalltotems/react-native-otp-input|react-native-iphone-x-helper|@react-native-picker|rn-range-slider|react-native-i18n|react-native-flash-message|react-native-linear-gradient|react-native-simple-radio-button|react-native-picker-select|react-native-config)\/)"
    ],
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing the good command. You should do `jest -t 'Verification Screen'`.

And if you have an `it` inside a `describe` block you have to run `jest -t '<describeString> <itString>'`

(thx to https://stackoverflow.com/a/42897994/12637199)